# org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor: ... Could not acquire lock on

Tags: java, locking, infinispan, timeoutexception

We're using infinispan 5.3.0 in a multi-server cluster for a Glassfish (3.1.2) application. The application has users processing events, which are stored in the infinispan cache.

During certain (peak?) times we are seeing a lot of the following stacktraces in the infinispan logs:

```
2015.04.24_14:41:47,482 - ERROR org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor: ISPN000136: Execution error [Thread=http-thread-pool-26861(93)]
org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Could not acquire lock on 66f2ebb9-cb22-4ba1-be6f-55ca0167cab6 on behalf of transaction GlobalTransaction:<[servername]-30723>:283157:local. Lock is being held by GlobalTransaction:<[servername]-59526>:141148:remote
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.newTimeoutException(AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.java:238)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.waitForTransactionsToComplete(AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.java:231)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.lockKeyAndCheckOwnership(AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.java:191)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.lockAndRegisterBackupLock(AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.java:136)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.PessimisticLockingInterceptor.visitLockControlCommand(PessimisticLockingInterceptor.java:255)
        at org.infinispan.commands.control.LockControlCommand.acceptVisitor(LockControlCommand.java:132)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:134)
        at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitLockControlCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:169)
        at org.infinispan.commands.control.LockControlCommand.acceptVisitor(LockControlCommand.java:132)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptorAndVerifyTransaction(TxInterceptor.java:130)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor.visitLockControlCommand(TxInterceptor.java:189)
        at org.infinispan.commands.control.LockControlCommand.acceptVisitor(LockControlCommand.java:132)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:134)
        at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitLockControlCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:169)
        at org.infinispan.statetransfer.TransactionSynchronizerInterceptor.visitLockControlCommand(TransactionSynchronizerInterceptor.java:97)
        at org.infinispan.commands.control.LockControlCommand.acceptVisitor(LockControlCommand.java:132)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
        at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.handleTopologyAffectedCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:216)
        at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.handleTxCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:189)
        at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferInterceptor.visitLockControlCommand(StateTransferInterceptor.java:131)
        at org.infinispan.commands.control.LockControlCommand.acceptVisitor(LockControlCommand.java:132)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:134)
        at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitLockControlCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:169)
        at org.infinispan.commands.control.LockControlCommand.acceptVisitor(LockControlCommand.java:132)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor.handleAll(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:128)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor.visitLockControlCommand(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:97)
        at org.infinispan.commands.control.LockControlCommand.acceptVisitor(LockControlCommand.java:132)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.InterceptorChain.invoke(InterceptorChain.java:343)
        at org.infinispan.CacheImpl.lock(CacheImpl.java:672)
        at org.infinispan.DecoratedCache.lock(DecoratedCache.java:139)


2015.04.24_14:46:39,010 - ERROR org.infinispan.remoting.InboundInvocationHandlerImpl: Exception executing command [Thread=remote-thread-13]
org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Could not acquire lock on [event-lock-id>] on behalf of transaction GlobalTransaction:<[servername]-37484>:26400:remote. Lock is being held by null
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.newTimeoutException(AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.java:238)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.waitForTransactionsToComplete(AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.java:231)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.lockKeyAndCheckOwnership(AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.java:191)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.lockAndRegisterBackupLock(AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.java:136)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.PessimisticLockingInterceptor.visitLockControlCommand(PessimisticLockingInterceptor.java:255)
        at org.infinispan.commands.control.LockControlCommand.acceptVisitor(LockControlCommand.java:132)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:134)
        at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitLockControlCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:169)
        at org.infinispan.commands.control.LockControlCommand.acceptVisitor(LockControlCommand.java:132)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptorAndVerifyTransaction(TxInterceptor.java:130)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor.visitLockControlCommand(TxInterceptor.java:189)
        at org.infinispan.commands.control.LockControlCommand.acceptVisitor(LockControlCommand.java:132)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:120)
        at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:134)
        at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitLockControlCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:169)
        at org.infinispan.statetransfer.TransactionSynchronizerInterceptor.visitLockControlCommand(TransactionSynchronizerInterceptor.java:94)
```

Has anbody an idea what's causing these errors or any pointers for further analysis?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Infinispan uses distributed locks to synchronize cache modification. The reason for this is the same as synchronizing multithreaded access to a variable. During peak times lock contention becomes too high, and some lock acquisition attempts time out. Consider increasing lock acquisition timeout or configure lock striping. For in-depth information see Infinispan User Guide: [5. Locking and Concurrency](http://infinispan.org/docs/5.3.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_locking_and_concurrency).

Comment: @ Vsevolod Golovanov - But I was expecting some turbulence in infinispan logs. Logs in infinispan server must indicate those timeouts or locks.  I do not see any footprints of such.  After restart of servers and some clients also the issue went away. But it left a Big question mark on infinispan cache servers.

Comment: @YS_NE, if you don't see lock timeouts like in the question here, then what's the issue? Or are you using a dedicated Infinispan Server, and you see timeouts in client logs, but not in server's? I don't know about this, I never used a dedicated server.